# Logstash debug to log files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, bigdata

Is it possible to create log files with logstash?

I know there is a -l/--log switch but is it possible to do it through the config file?
Thank you.

Comment: Why you need such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Open

```
/etc/logstash/logstash.yml
```

and add/change the following lines:

```
log.level: debug
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
```

Restart logstash and this will generate logs in:

```
/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log
```