# logstash sending to https server: [HTTP Output Failure] Could not fetch URL

Tags: json, https, logstash

client is using logstash to send to our https server, format is json. The sending rate is  500 eps, not high. We could get some data, but sometimes logstash side has below error. Could anyone help, how to fix this. Thanks

```
[2023-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx,xxx][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ][main][e939f55c8a49efb231738689491d86258dcce3b80aa0a101617b4df7fe32e4ed] [HTTP Output Failure] Could not fetch URL {:url=>https://xxxx:5555/foo, :method=>:post, :message=>"xxxx:5555 failed to respond", :class=>"Manticore::ClientProtocolException", :will_retry=>true}
```

output sec should be like below

```
output {
  http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "https://xxxx:5555/foo"
    format => "json"
    headers => {
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message suggests that Logstash is having trouble sending data to your HTTPS server at the specified URL. It mentions a Manticore::ClientProtocolException, which typically indicates a problem with the underlying HTTP client library used by Logstash. This could be due to various reasons, such as network issues, server issues, or configuration problems.

- Ensure that there are no network issues between the Logstash server and the HTTPS server.
  Verify that the HTTPS server is up and running and can accept incoming connections on port 5555.

  ```
  telnet server_ip_or_hostname 5555
  ```
- Check the logs on your HTTPS server for any errors or issues that might prevent it from responding to incoming requests.
- Ensure that the Logstash configuration you provided is correct and complete.
  Verify that the Logstash server has access to the HTTPS server URL.
  Double-check the URL, port, and path in your Logstash configuration to make sure they are correct.
- If your HTTPS server uses SSL/TLS, make sure that Logstash is configured to trust the server's SSL certificate. You may need to specify the certificate authority (CA) or certificate file in the Logstash configuration. For details, Check here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/secure-logstash-connections.html

If you still can find the issue. You can [try enabling debug mode in logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166339/logstash-debug-to-log-files) to check for the issue.